# multiline text display in razor core

Tags: razor, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

I've taken multiline input with textarea html tag eg:

```
line 1
line 2 with <tags> and &#64; and <b> bold </b>
line 3
```

but how can I later display this?

If I use:

```
@Html.DisplayFor(m => m.MultilineText2)
```

it handles the special characters fine, but not the linebreak

If I use:

```
@Html.Raw(Model.MultilineText2.Replace(Environment.NewLine, "<br/>"))
```

it handles the linebreak, but not the special chars.

I just want the result to appear exactly as the user entered it (exactly as you see it in the example above)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I understand correctly, what you want is to encode everything else except the linebreakers. But you don't need to care about that. Since there's a standard way  by [`white-space`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/white-space) :

> **pre-line**
>
> Sequences of white space are collapsed. Lines are broken at newline characters, at 
> , and as necessary to fill line boxes.

So, simply adding a `white-space: pre-line` will work:

```
<span style="white-space: pre-line">@Html.DisplayFor(m => m.MultilineText2)</span>
```

the generated html will be :

```html
<span style="white-space: pre-line">line 1
 line 2 with &lt;tags&gt; and &amp;#64; and &lt;b&gt; bold &lt;/b&gt;
line 3</span>
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Just use @Html.TextAreaFor(m => m.fieldName)

Comment: Thanks for the reply, I've tested this, but this is not the desired result.  I already got the input from a textarea tag, now I just want to display it as non-editable text on another page.